# How buildings 3D model is created

Tags: structural-engineering, cad, building-design

Suppose I have a rough 3d model of a building created it some CAD software. Now I want to change some portion of the model based on the following factors

- Lighting
- Energy consumption
- Structural Load
- Fire Safety
- Heating & cooling load
- etc.

Is there any Software that can provide these feature. I know there are some good software for each of the feature mentioned above, but how can we integrate their results into the 3d model. I am from a Computer science background so don't have much idea about this, Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site. Or check [SoftwareRecs.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good Starting point for what you need is REVIT:

Our structural engineers do not use REVIT. They use RAM Steel to perform their structural analysis (Gravity only) and then give the work to CAD operators to document in AutoCAD or Revit.

A lot of the building Components can be stress tested with  multiple scenarios in INVENTOR per individual components, but they also can be done in revit if you know the know how. (this is much more complex)